# react-native-maps : How to follow user location on button press

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) and it works great. But I have two problems.

1. I am able to follow user location automatically using the `followsUserLocation` but when I move the map it keeps dragging me back to the user location. How could I fix this?
2. I want to have refresh button, and when the user press the button, I want my map view to follow user location.

   ```
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
           followsUserLocation: true,
       };
   }


   mapView() {
       return(
           <MapView style={styles.map}
           showsUserLocation
           followsUserLocation={this.state.followsUserLocation}
           initialRegion={{
           latitude: 37.523814,
           longitude:  126.927494,
           latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
           longitudeDelta: 0.0421}}/>
      )
   }
   ```

Any comments or advise would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try onUserLocationChange callback and set your region accordingly using setState

```
   state = {
    showsUserLocation: true,
    followsUserLocation : true,
    mapRegion: {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    },
  };
```

```
    <MapView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            region={this.state.mapRegion}
            //use this callback to update the regions
            onUserLocationChange={event => console.log(event.nativeEvent)}
            showsUserLocation={this.state.showsUserLocation}
            followsUserLocation={this.state.followsUserLocation}
          />
```

Comment: In the callback onUserLocationChange set followsUserLocation = false

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with Reack Hook
you can create a **var** instead of useState.
In my case to prevent the app from crashing handled with the ternary condition.

```
  var liveMap = {
mapRegion: {
  latitude: lattitude ? lattitude : 19.88134866090193,
  longitude: longitude ? longitude : 73.97658792586263,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0022,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0021,
},



     <MapView
        mapType="satellite"
        style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}
        showsUserLocation={false}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        zoomControlEnabled={true}
        followsUserLocation={true}
        // onUserLocationChange={(event) => console.log("this is event",event.nativeEvent)}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        followsUserLocation={true}
        region={liveMap.mapRegion}
        // initialRegion={{
        //   latitude: lattitude ? lattitude : 19.88134866090193,
        //   longitude: longitude ? longitude : 73.97658792586263,
        //   latitudeDelta: 0.0022,
        //   longitudeDelta: 0.0021,
        // }}
      >
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: lattitude ? lattitude : 19.88134866090193,
            longitude: longitude ? longitude : 73.97658792586263,
          }}
          title={"JavaTpoint"}
          description={"Java Training Institute"}
        />
      </MapView>
```